# crontab emails me that /bin/bash/ mail or /bin/bash mailx is not found

Tags: email, cron, centos7, incrontab

**Update**: cron string is now correct in structure.

I have the `mailto:user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com` option configured in my `crontab`

I have this crontask scheduled right now:

*/5 * * * * root /bin/bash /scripts/db-bkup-test &>/tmp/myDbBack.log;
 mailx -s "Nightly Test Database Back-up Is Running Successfully" user@domain.com,user1@domain.com

*/5 * * * * root /bin/bash /scripts/db-bkup-test &>/tmp/myDbBack.log;
 mail -s "Nightly Test Database Back-up Is Running Successfully" user@domain.com,user1@domain.com

I get the errors that /bin/bash mail cannot be found in an email. I find this hilarious. So how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you edit your cron file:

```
crontab -e
```

Here is an example of basic cronjob which dumps the database every 6 hours and sends an email, the email will contains whatever the command outputs to standard output to Tom Hanks and Tom Cruise:

```
MAILTO="tom@hanks.com,tom@cruise.com"
0 */6 * * * mysqldump -u tom_hanks -pHANKS_TOM --host=10.0.0.1 mycompany > /home/tom_hanks/db.sql
```

Now for **mail** command to work, you will need a MTA agent. Install postfix to get the mail command through your terminal in ubuntu/debian:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y postfix mailutils
```

or

```
sudo dnf update && sudo dnf install postfix mailx -y
```

replace dnf with yum for older Redhat or Fedora.

For **mailx** you can install **bsd-mailx** on ubuntu/debian:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bsd-mailx
```

If you already have postfix installed, you can troubleshoot using this command in a terminal on ubuntu/debian:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Open port 25 using iptables:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Since you want root to run the cronjob, use

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then add your cronjob like this:

```
*/5 * * * * sh /scripts/db-bkup-test.sh &> /tmp/myDbBack.log &&  mail -s "Nightly Test Database Back-up Is Running Successfully" user@domain.com,user1@domain.com < /dev/null
```

mail command will need a email body which we are providing null (nothing)

Answer (score 0):

So not really familiar with linux server side, figured it out. I installed mailx.

> yum install mailx

[Using this source.](https://tecadmin.net/bash-mail-command-not-found/)

I tested the service using cmd:

```
$ mailx -s 'Test' user@domain.com > /dev/null
```

Updated the cron to reflect the empty body same as above `> /dev/null`